# Confusion with adjusting: adding all predictors into one model or running multiple models

Tags: regression, adjustment

I generally understand quite well the idea of adjusting; however, the current study design is killing me. Despite hours and hours of thinking (and my head almost explode), I still don't know, which modelling structure would be right for my study question.

**Question:** Do different local health care offers explain COVID-19 complications rate in a country?

Local health care offer rates are available for each region in the country, and I have three different kinds of them: offer_1, offer_2, offer_3. All continuous variables.

DAG would say, that offers can be associated with each other (though nobody knows the direction of this association), and they should be associated with complications.

**Thus, should I model them separately:**

complications ~ offer_1 + region

complications ~ offer_2 + region

complications ~ offer_3 + region

**Or should I put them consequently into one model:**

complications ~ offer_1 + offer_2 + offer_3 + region

If possible, could you explain why I should choose one to another?

Comment: Your formulas seem to conceive of "health care offers" as if they were three separate variables, but aren't they just three possible levels of a *single* categorical variable?  Please clarify.

Comment: Thanks! The offers reflect service accessibility (offered hours per capita in region). Thus, they are continuous variables with non-normal distributions.

Comment: In that case it would likely be erroneous to model them separately, because you would never be accounting for associations among the offers.

Answer (score 1):

I´d think it depends on your problem and available resources.

Considering them as a separately models, they will produce three different outputs, each one of them would have a specific value related to the weight of every offer into the region. Then, combining these results would be using an esemble technique, like a mean over the results.

On the other hand, putting them into a single model would make those weights into a single matrix, having a single model tackling your entire problem.

Of course both approaches have their advantages and disadvantages:

1. For the first option, the overfitting won´t be a problem, because every model would be specialized in each problem. Also, you could give every model an importance, so you could decide whether a result is more or less important than other. The downside is the available resources to train and store every model.
2. For the second option, you could lead with overfitting problems, because the model try to generalize all offers into a single matrix (instead of three), but memory won´t be a problem for you.

In my humble opinion, I´d prefer the first option, because you could focus your efforts on optimizing specialized models, instead of dealing with a single model trying to manage all information.

Hope it is useful for you.

Comment: Thank you so much! The output of the first option is simple to interpret? If offer_1 showed a negative association with complications, thus, regions with higher offer_1 are more protected against COVID-19 complications. The second option also takes into account the relative associations between the offers? For instance, if offer_3 shows negative linear association with complications, thus, the interpretation would be: regions with higher offer_3 values in relation to other offer types are more protected against COVID-19 complications?

Comment: Both options take into consideration your associations, even more because we´re takling about linear models. In the other hand, interpretations would depend entirely in your observations, having a negative linear association could lead into saying more protection against COVID-19 complicatinos, of course you need to ensure no other variables are affecting your results. Remember not all correlations means causation ;)